# Any way to full screen a .exe in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

Need to open notepad and write a message in Robot Framework, would like this window to span the whole screen to warn others to not use the current machine. Any way this is possible using Robot frameworks built in or external libraries?

Comment: Is your goal specifically to open notepad, or is your goal to cover the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that if you want to do this on the desktop itself, using key combinations would be best. In [this list][1] there are over 100 combinations.

In order to maximize an application in focus, using WIN + ARROW UP